# Как изменить стандартную высоту строки в DataGrid Blazorise

Tags: css, datagrid, blazor

Я хочу изменить стандартную высоту строки в DataGrid Blazorise. Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Код ниже работает частично, цвет меняется, высота нет.

```
public void OnRowStyling(TEntity entity, DataGridRowStyling styling)
            => styling.Style = "color: red; height: 10px;";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void OnRowStyling(TEntity entity, DataGridRowStyling styling)
{
    styling.Class = "row-height-10px";
}
```

Затем

```
.row-height-10px {
    height: 10px;
}
```

Используй метод `styling.AddClass`

```
public void OnRowStyling(TEntity entity, DataGridRowStyling styling)
{
    styling.AddClass("row-height-10px");
}
```

Теперь высота строк должна быть равна 10 пикс.

Comment: Я думал о таком подходе, но почему таки Style не работает. И еще - нет у меня метода AddClass, есть только свойство Class. Попробую, конечно. Спасибо. Хотя хотелось бы обойтись стайлом.

Comment: В Blazorise DataGrid, свойство "Style" может использоваться для назначения индивидуальных стилей для ячейки, а не для строки. Вам нужно использовать свойство "Class" для назначения класса строке. Почему св-во "Style" не работает для изменения высоты строки, возможно, потому что другие стили, которые используются в DataGrid, могут переопределять ваш стиль. Привязка класса на уровне строки должна позволить изменить высоту строки как задумано. По поводу метода AddClass - он используется для добавления класса к существующему св-у Class, вы можете просто присвоить новое значение свойству Class.

Comment: Свойство Style работает, просто в 10 px не лез контент. Проблемы еще остались, но это уже другой вопрос. Я понимаю для чего нужен метод AddClass, но у меня его просто нет. Возможно, что-то не подгружено, да и бог с ним. При необходимости обойдусь свойством Class. Вам все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, значение 10px оказалось слишком мало для внутреннего контента строки. Свойство Style рабочее.